# JIT compilation failed, no more memory in phar

Tags: php, composer

I need to begin learning php and the laravel framework for my new job. However, I am stumped on how to properly install laravel using composer. When I try to install laravel using composer, I get this error:

[ErrorException]
  preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory

PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php on line 199

As well as a few other errors on different lines. Can someone please help?

Thank you!
Jake

Comment: Could it be due to [Bug #77260 preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77260)? Its description seems to match your case, its status is currently open and starts from PHP 7.3.0. I was experiencing the same issue on 7.3.3 and downgrading to 7.2.16 seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest set in **php.ini** `pcre.jit = 0`.
You may read more here [Bug #77260  preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77260)